# Checking input value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, input, numbers

I am trying to check whether the user gives an input that is number but not letters. When a non-numeric value is given I want to print an alert error message like "incorrect format".

This is my source code:

```
-(IBAction)btnPressed{

    NSString *firstString = textFiled1.text;
    NSString *secondString = textFiled2.text;
    NSString *thirdString = textFiled3.text;

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    int output;

    num1 = [firstString intValue];
    num2 = [secondString intValue];
    num3 = [thirdString intValue];

    output = (num1 + num2) / num3;

    lable1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",output];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
NSCharacterSet *nonNumbers = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
if ([firstString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumbers].location != NSNotFound) {
    // firstString has non-number characters in it!
}
```

Comment: This won't work properly though, because `decimalDigitCharacterSet` includes *more than just 0 through to 9*, it includes digits in other scripts/languages as well. Also, this will fail if the input is negative (which was not stipulated as a requirement but must be considered either way).

Comment: I suppose that's true. It's easy to use the same basic method with a character set including '-' (and '.' for that matter). The fact that the character set contains non-arabic digits in indeed a failing here. However, in some situations that may actually be desired.

Answer (score 4):

Use NSNumberFormatter. If the input parameter is not a valid number, the number derived will be nil.

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
num1 = [f numberFromString:firstString];
[f release];

if (num1 == nil) {
// throw exception
}
```

Comment: I am new to Xcode. Could you help me more where should I write this code?

Comment: Right after you get your firstString. i.e after NSString *firstString = textFiled1.text; make sure you define num1 as NSNumber though instead of int.

Comment: I have  the NSSting to NSNumber (incompatible pointer type initializing) but it works without it still accept letters. But what I want is it doesn't accept letter only numbers. Could you help me please?

Comment: This is the better way to do it because the NSNumberFormatter class was designed for converting numbers to-and-from strings.